# What are some good, IP Address Management solutions for IPv6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipam

There are a number of open source IPAM tools available for IPv4 address management; however there seems to be a distinct lack of actively updated tools available for IPv6.

Other than FreeIPdb (code no longer maintained) or the RIPE Database (I have seen some customisations to the RIPEdb that allow for enterprise/ISP IPAM but it seems like overkill for a system that will probably only ever handle one /32 worth of space).

Are there any other options that I'm missing?

(Database only please.  I know vi can be used for flat text IPAM, that's how I'm handling our /32 at the moment, but I don't see it scaling for much longer)

It doesn't have to be open source but what are folks doing to manage IPv6 in a dual stack environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While demand for IPv6 IPAM tools is increasing, almost none of the current Open Source products have added IPv6 capabilities. The commercial vendors (Alcatel-Lucent, Bluecat, Infoblox, and INS) are really the only ones with the credible solutions at this point.

Comment: In your opinion, how credible are these solutions?  Presentations / demos I have seen have been very lacking on detail on the IPv6 side of these products and I get the feeling that a lot of it is vaporware.

Comment: All of my work with these commercial vendors has been strictly IPv4, and so you made me think about this.  Most of these vendors only have cursory support for IPv6.  They all seem to miss the mark when it comes to full IPAM of ipv6 especially visualization. I still have feelers out to a specialist in the IPv6 space, and am soliciting his feedback.  Let you know if anything turns up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First off, I'm the owner of an open source project called http://opennetadmin.com.  It is an IPAM solution that does all the typical things you would expect.  It of course was built initially as an IPv4 tool.

I have a bit of work done in the system to support IPv6 but my problem is this.  I don't get to use IPv6 on a regular basis so all of the real world testing and experience that I have in designing the IPv4 stuff is lacking in the IPv6 world.

Sure I know my share about IPv6 and I've set up a few networks and used tunnel brokers but I'm just not comfortable with my knowledge to design a proper application for it.

I have IPv6 on my list o things to do but lack some key design discussions as well as anyone to help test things out in a true environment.

I'd say anyone who wants to contribute design ideas and "I wish the tool would just do XYZ" please come post in the opennetadmin forums so we can discuss details and solutions.

Sooo.. not really an answer but maybe a path to one.........

Comment: FYI, OpenNetAdmin now has initial support for IPv6.  Its in the ipv6 branch of the subversion repository.  More testing needed but it is now in a usable state.

Answer (score 3):

[NOC's IPAM](http://redmine.nocproject.org/wiki/noc/IPAM) has full IPv6 support. There are some screencasts on site, demonstrating
basic IPAM functions.

Answer (score 2):

The new version 3.0 of the open source IPAM tool GestióIP supports IPv6.
Here are some screenshots:
http://www.gestioip.net/screenshots_gestioip_en.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check out www.6connect.net - our IPAM solution was built for IPv6 natively with added IPv4 support - it is the only tool out there in use that is actually built by network engineers for network engineers

Answer (score 0):

How about you pay a developer to add it to an opensource solution? May cost a few hundred dollars, but it'll give you "free" PR.

Comment: Very true, and this is one of the options I am presenting to my employer.  I'm not holding my breath for a favourable outcome though.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Address_Management) claims that IPplan's beta of 6.00 has IPv6 support.  Certainly it's right at the top of their feature list for the beta, so you could perhaps point some developer support in their direction to get that feature out of beta.  They look to be deep into a bug-fixing stage for IPv6 and have frozen their IPv4 only release verson since 2009.